# Pandas - calculate rolling average of group excluding current row

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

For an example:

```
data = {'Platoon': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],
        'Date' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
       'Casualties': [1,4,5,7,5,5,6,1,4,5,6,7,4,6,4,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This works to calculate the rolling average, inclusive of the current row:

```
df['avg'] = df.groupby(['Platoon'])['Casualties'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2, 1).mean())
```

Which gives:

```
Platoon   Date Casualties Avg  
        A   1   1         1.0
        A   2   4         2.5
        A   3   5         4.5
        A   4   7         6.0
        ......
```

What I want to get is:

```
Platoon   Date Casualties Avg  
        A   1   1         1.0
        A   2   4         1.0
        A   3   5         2.5
        A   4   7         4.5
        ......
```

I suspect I can use shift here but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `shift` with `bfill`

```
df.groupby(['Platoon'])['Casualties'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2, 1).mean().shift().bfill())
```