# How to aggregate only values in the prceding and following values of a column in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In sql window functions we can use  window aggregations like below

mean('c') over (partition by 'a' order by 'b' rows between preceding 30 and following 20)

Is there a way in python (simple way like in sql above ) to compute these (rows between preceding, following, currentrow)

Comment: Pandas has [well documented window functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html), what have you tried so far? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: thanks for the documentation link, I have tried the rolling earlier. but rolling compute aggregations including the current value. right ? one example I am thinking is how to compute a rolling previous 30 day average (not including that current row's value) of a column, which can be done like ( .... rows between 30 preceding and 1 preceding)  in sql. wondering how the same can be done in python/pandas

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622062/pandas-calculate-rolling-average-of-group-excluding-current-row) has a method for using `.shift` and `bfill` to exclude the current row from a grouped rolling function, does that help answer your question? Beyond that, please provide sample input and output to help us better understand and assist (as in the minimal example link above)

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you. I got it now